# Fancy Bubble chart D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to ask if anyone know how to get the code to do similar chart like this https://www.theguardian.com/world/interactive/2013/feb/12/state-of-the-union-reading-level 
It is written in D3 but I couldn't find similar codes online.

Thanks

Comment: https://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/02/sotu/js/main.js is the link to their js.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a fairly involved tooltip on a scatter plot.  Here's a simpler [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369):

```
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
  .attr("class", "tooltip")             
  .style("opacity", 0);

// Add the scatterplot
svg.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(data)         
.enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5)       
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })     
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
```

You might also find [this other example](http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069) useful.

Comment: Many thanks. your examples are very useful and will use this simpler version